# The list of Tagged questions is not refreshing immediately when the tag is removed from a question

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, live-refresh, caching

I recently edited a question and removed the tag `mdx` from it as it had got nothing to do with that. When I went to the tag `MDX`, I could still see this question even though it didn't have the `MDX` tag in it.

**EDIT:** While I was framing this question, I did one more refresh, and that question had disappeared. I am guessing some worker job is running on some frequency, which updates the list. Since the question had disappeared, I had to temporarily edit one question remove the tag and then add it back to prove my point.

In light of the above, I am tagging this as a bug, but probably is just an observation and better treated that way.

[image]

Comment: Obligatory comment blaming caching...

Comment: why, oh why is there no [meta-tag:status-caching]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're seeing the effect of [caching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/221414#221414) and the time needed to propagate the changes to all servers.

If you would have kept refreshing that page you sometimes can observe that on one page load the question(s) are gone and on the next they are all back again. That depends on which server in the server farm is serving the page. The effect is even more clear if you're burninating a tag.

If you want to read more about the search indexing make sure you check the posts from [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) on the subject, for example in his answer on [How does Stack Overflow implement its search indexing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187501/158100)